# Expected value of winning with a Random Uniform Variable

Tags: probability, uniform-distribution

I have this small homework I don't quite understand.

The problem is formulated as a game. (Who wants to be millionaire)

You start with 1£. money = 1.0£

You can choose to quit at anytime 
So you can quit immediately without answering and still have 1£.

You will be given a question with a probability p of answering correctly.

If you answer wisely you double up and get 2£. If you answer poorly you lose everything and get 0£.

The probability p is not exactly known but is a uniform distributed variable between 0.3 and 1.0

What is the expected value of the money you'll earn? E(money). The correct answer is 1.357 **if there is only one question.**

My best guess is p = (1.0 + 0.3)/2

E(money) = 1.0 + 2.0*p - 1.0*(1-p) = 1.95 which is the wrong answer...

My homework is about finding an algorithm for more than 1 question, however i fail to understand for just 1.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: "What is the expected value of the money you'll earn?" Assuming you follow which strategy?

Comment: No strategy needed. The probability that you answer correctly is somewhere between 0.3 and 1.0

Comment: Sure but at any time you have to decide whether to quit or to continue.

Comment: I suppose the strategy then is to quit right after when you've won the expected value of money. But the strategy is not really the main concern. Oh when i mean the correct answer is 1.357 i meant if there is only 1 single question.

Comment: Then the expected value of the money one will earn is 1.3, not 1.357. Sorry but your question is unclear.

Comment: No the probability p is between 0.3 and 1.0 its not 0.3

Comment: I know, otherwise one would lose money, on average. Your comment is unrelated. Why do you think the expected value of the money one will earn is 1.357?

Comment: How did you come up with 1.3?

Comment: 1.357 is given to me in the problem text as an example.

Comment: Either there is something wrong with the wording or the numbers. I also came up with $1.3$, with 2 different methods.